# How to make geom_errorbar() the same color as the fill of points when using border customizable pch in ggplot R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using the special pch (21-25) to make a scatter plot with `ggplot` since I want the fill of the points to vary with factor levels, but I also want the border of the points to be fixed as black. I wish to add an error bar to each of the points and I want the error bar to be the same color as the fill of the points. However, since I'm fixing the `colour` aesthetic of points to black and `geom_errorbar()` uses this to plot the color of the error bars I can't seem to figure out how to get the result I want.

Here is a simple example where I'm getting the undesired result (black color in the error bars):

```
library(ggplot2)
test <- cbind.data.frame(
  x = rnorm(10),
  y = rnorm(10),
  stdv = sd(rnorm(10)),
  fl = c(rep("foo", 5), rep("bar", 5))
)

ggplot(data = test, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = fl, fill = fl, ymin = y - stdv, ymax = y + stdv)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 3) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = rep("black", nrow(test))) +
  geom_errorbar()
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `new_scale_color()` from `ggnewscale` package (for sure this a trick I learnt from **@AllanCameron**):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)
#Data
test <- cbind.data.frame(
  x = rnorm(10),
  y = rnorm(10),
  stdv = sd(rnorm(10)),
  fl = c(rep("foo", 5), rep("bar", 5))
)
#Plot
ggplot(data = test, aes(x = x, y = y,
                        colour = fl, 
                        fill = fl,
                        ymin = y - stdv,
                        ymax = y + stdv)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 3) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = rep("black", nrow(test))) +
  new_scale_color()+
  geom_errorbar(aes(color=fl))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This works very nicely. Just for completeness, my guess is that something like this is not possible to do without an external package right?

Comment: @MikeKatz45 It can be very complex without that package but it is possible :)

Answer (score 2):

Any reason you're using `scale_colour_manual()` instead of just using `colour = "black"`? If your actual example allows you to use that, then, you don't need ggnewscale:

```r
library(ggplot2)
test <- cbind.data.frame(
  x = rnorm(10),
  y = rnorm(10),
  stdv = sd(rnorm(10)),
  fl = c(rep("foo", 5), rep("bar", 5))
)

ggplot(data = test, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = fl, fill = fl, ymin = y - stdv, ymax = y + stdv)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 3, colour = "black") +
  geom_errorbar()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>